Nx module boundaries error on @angular/core
I have created a Nx Standalone Angular project and then created a local library, as described in the official documentation.
I am trying to add a lint rule to enforce module boundaries. I am using the following configuration:
"@nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
   "error",
   {
      // "allow": ["@angular/**"],
      "enforceBuildableLibDependency": true,
      "allow": [],
      "depConstraints": [
         {
            "sourceTag": "scope:main",
            "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": [
               "scope:main",
               "scope:my-components"
             ]
          }
      ]
   }
]

where scope:main is the tag in the application and  scope:my-components is the tag I am using in the local library. The problem is that the linter complains about Angular's imports such as @angular/core.
The error reads:
Projects should use relative imports to import from other files within the same project. Use "./path/to/file" instead of import from "@angular/core" (eslint@nx/enforce-module-boundaries)
The only solution I found so far is to add the commented-out line "allow": ["@angular/**"].
But this looks like a workaround to me. Shouldn't this work without this line?

As it turns out, the problem was that I was using pnpm...
I don't know why, but after trying with npm, everything worked without the need for the allow workaround.
